# Username and password files in Kali

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, telnet

I'm new to pen-testing world. I'm trying to learn how to gain access through telnet service opened on port 23.

I'm using Metasploit. The first approach I'm trying is using the `telnet_login` module to try a dictionary attack on the target.
I've seen that I should set `USER_FILE`  and `PASS_FILE`.

Does Kali have sample **user.txt** and **pass.txt** files? 
Are there better approaches to attack telnet service?

Comment: Kali is very well documented and every tool has its own documentation. https://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/wordlists

Comment: Also note that there is a difference between Kali and Metasploit. Kali is just a Linux distribution. The tools that come bundled with Kali are the ones that you use.

Comment: Anyway what about the second question? Are there other way to take advantages of telnet other than enforce the login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kali contains built in password word lists. They are compressed and can be found at:

```
/usr/share/wordlists/
```

I'm unaware of username lists, since usernames are usually pretty dependent on the format the service uses, and are typically fairly unique.

You can put together a simple non-exhaustive word lists for the users yourself containing obvious potential names such as:

- admin
- local
- root
- user
- remote

Since you're using this to attack your own system though, you should already know what the username is, so you can just list that.

A brief reminder that you shouldn't use a tool like this to attack a system you don't have explicit permission to access. That would be a crime.